# In Microsoft Office Outlook 2010, how can I manually purge mails that are marked for deletion in IMAP folders?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, imap, ribbon

As described in the header I can not find the button for purging mails manually that I have marked for deletion in an IMAP folder.

The Problem only occours in Outlook 2010

Answer (score 0):

I've found that (in Outlook 2007 anyway) the only trigger to get the IMAP folders to purge is to leave the folder (click on a different (IMAP) folder) and go back into it.

I was hoping there would be a better way in 2010 (which I don't use yet), but your question is leading me to believe that's not the case. :(

Comment: actually, there is! I found a button in options dialog (customize ribbon). If you post it / put a screenshot, I'll honor it with +1 & _correct answer_...