# How to get Outlook 2010 to detect IMAP messages deleted from another machine?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, imap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Microsoft Office Outlook 2010, how can I manually purge mails that are marked for deletion in IMAP folders?](https://superuser.com/questions/279979/in-microsoft-office-outlook-2010-how-can-i-manually-purge-mails-that-are-marked)

I have an IMAP account (not Gmail) that I'm accessing from several machines and can access via a web site.  I'm trying to find a way to get Outlook 2010 to detect when a message has been deleted and make it go away.

Here is an example:

1. Have a message in the Inbox - it shows on machine A and machine B
2. Delete the message using the mail client on machine B
3. Go to machine A and check mail - the message is still there in Outlook

I've confirmed that the message is gone on the server (not just marked deleted but expunged) but Outlook will keep showing the message.  The only way it'll disappear is to switch to a different folder and come back.

This DOES work with Windows Live Mail - whenever it checks for mail if the message is no longer on the server it disappears from the view.  But I'd like to use Outlook 2010.

I tried using Thunderbird and it has the same problem.  You'd think this would work since the idea of IMAP is to be able to sync with messages on the server.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe that one is talking about how to expunge the message which is a little different.

Comment: It's the same answer, and in reality the same problem.  Outlook doesn't update changed (IMAP) items (i.e.: marked as deleted and waiting for purge, or deleted elsewhere, or changed elsewhere) until you leave and re-enter the folder containing the message in question.